# Playframwork 2.5 cannot compile "play java seed" app after create

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.5

I'm trying play framework 2.5.4 following this tutorial:

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/Installing

I created an app from "Play Scala Seed" template, It works fine.

But when I created an app from "Play Java Seed" template, it cannot be compiled.

I try to read error message but I have no hint to solve this problem.

This is the detail error message:

```
        Read from stdout: Compiling 6 Scala sources and 10 Java sources to D:\thanhpt\self-study\play framework\play-java\target\scala-2.11\classes...
Compiling 6 Scala sources and 10 Java sources to D:\thanhpt\self-study\play framework\play-java\target\scala-2.11\classes...
Read from stdout: D:\thanhpt\self-study\play framework\play-java\app\controllers\AsyncController.java:47:  error: ')' expected
D:\thanhpt\self-study\play framework\play-java\app\controllers\AsyncController.java:47:  error: ')' expected
Read from stdout: return getFutureMessage(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS).thenApplyAsync(Results::ok, exec);
Read from stdout: ^
        return getFutureMessage(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS).thenApplyAsync(Results::ok, exec);
                                                                           ^
D:\thanhpt\self-study\play framework\play-java\app\controllers\AsyncController.java:47:  error: illegal start of expression
Read from stdout: D:\thanhpt\self-study\play framework\play-java\app\controllers\AsyncController.java:47:  error: illegal start of expression
Read from stdout: return getFutureMessage(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS).thenApplyAsync(Results::ok, exec);
Read from stdout: ^
        return getFutureMessage(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS).thenApplyAsync(Results::ok, exec);
                                                                            ^
Read from stdout: D:\thanhpt\self-study\play framework\play-java\app\controllers\AsyncController.java:47:  error: ';' expected
D:\thanhpt\self-study\play framework\play-java\app\controllers\AsyncController.java:47:  error: ';' expected
Read from stdout: return getFutureMessage(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS).thenApplyAsync(Results::ok, exec);
Read from stdout: ^
        return getFutureMessage(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS).thenApplyAsync(Results::ok, exec);
                                                                                 ^
Read from stdout: D:\thanhpt\self-study\play framework\play-java\app\controllers\AsyncController.java:54:  error: illegal start of expression
D:\thanhpt\self-study\play framework\play-java\app\controllers\AsyncController.java:54:  error: illegal start of expression
Read from stdout: () -> future.complete("Hi!"),
Read from stdout: ^
            () -> future.complete("Hi!"),
             ^
Read from stdout: D:\thanhpt\self-study\play framework\play-java\app\controllers\AsyncController.java:54:  error: illegal start of expression
D:\thanhpt\self-study\play framework\play-java\app\controllers\AsyncController.java:54:  error: illegal start of expression
Read from stdout: () -> future.complete("Hi!"),
Read from stdout: ^
            () -> future.complete("Hi!"),
                ^
Read from stdout: D:\thanhpt\self-study\play framework\play-java\app\filters\ExampleFilter.java:40:  error: illegal start of expression
D:\thanhpt\self-study\play framework\play-java\app\filters\ExampleFilter.java:40:  error: illegal start of expression
Read from stdout: result -> result.withHeader("X-ExampleFilter", "foo"),
Read from stdout: ^
            result -> result.withHeader("X-ExampleFilter", "foo"),
                    ^
Read from stdout: D:\thanhpt\self-study\play framework\play-java\app\services\ApplicationTimer.java:42:  error: illegal start of expression
D:\thanhpt\self-study\play framework\play-java\app\services\ApplicationTimer.java:42:  error: illegal start of expression
Read from stdout: appLifecycle.addStopHook(() -> {
Read from stdout: ^
        appLifecycle.addStopHook(() -> {
                                  ^
Read from stdout: D:\thanhpt\self-study\play framework\play-java\app\services\ApplicationTimer.java:42:  error: illegal start of expression
D:\thanhpt\self-study\play framework\play-java\app\services\ApplicationTimer.java:42:  error: illegal start of expression
Read from stdout: appLifecycle.addStopHook(() -> {
Read from stdout: ^
    appLifecycle.addStopHook(() -> {
                                 ^
Read from stdout: D:\thanhpt\self-study\play framework\play-java\app\services\ApplicationTimer.java:42:  error: illegal start of expression
D:\thanhpt\self-study\play framework\play-java\app\services\ApplicationTimer.java:42:  error: illegal start of expression
Read from stdout: appLifecycle.addStopHook(() -> {
Read from stdout: ^
        appLifecycle.addStopHook(() -> {
                                       ^
Read from stdout: D:\thanhpt\self-study\play framework\play-java\app\services\ApplicationTimer.java:42:  error: ';' expected
D:\thanhpt\self-study\play framework\play-java\app\services\ApplicationTimer.java:42:  error: ';' expected
Read from stdout: appLifecycle.addStopHook(() -> {
Read from stdout: ^
        appLifecycle.addStopHook(() -> {
                                        ^
Read from stdout: D:\thanhpt\self-study\play framework\play-java\app\services\ApplicationTimer.java:47:  error: illegal start of type
D:\thanhpt\self-study\play framework\play-java\app\services\ApplicationTimer.java:47:  error: illegal start of type
Read from stdout: });
Read from stdout: ^
        });
         ^
Read from stdout: D:\thanhpt\self-study\play framework\play-java\app\services\ApplicationTimer.java:50:  error: class, interface, or enum expected
D:\thanhpt\self-study\play framework\play-java\app\services\ApplicationTimer.java:50:  error: class, interface, or enum expected
Read from stdout: }
Read from stdout: ^
}
^
Read from stdout: (compile:compileIncremental) javac returned nonzero exit code
(compile:compileIncremental) javac returned nonzero exit code
Total time: 2 s, completed Jun 14, 2016 2:34:23 PM
```

[image]

I'm using:

1. Windows 7
2. Java 8
3. activator-dist-1.3.10
4. Play 2.5.4

How to solve this problem?

Comment: I'd guess you used an older Java, older than 8. Are you sure that your compiler compliance level is 1.8?

Comment: There are some different version Java s on my PC. Although I set JAVA_HOME and PATH variable refer to jdk8\bin folder, It seem older Java is still used. Finally, I tried to revise PATH variable to make sure jdk8 is used. It works fine. In conclusion, I have to use java 8, if older this error will happen. Thank you very much for you suggestion @Kris.